# PHP Regex Match Text Between quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text....

B/H888/QG and I would like to extract the H888 from this.  There will always be two forwards slashes encapsulating this.

```
$subject = "B/H888/QG";
$pattern = '/(.+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The best I can get to is the above however this is completely wrong and outputs

H888/QG!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a regex? Just use [explode](http://php.net/explode).

```
$subject = "B/H888/QG";
$pieces = explode( '/', $subject);
echo $pieces[1]; // Outputs H888
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4iNQWJ)

If you must use a regex, you need something like this:

```
$subject = "B/H888/QG";
$pattern = '/\/([\w\d]+)\//';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // Outputs H888
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LAAKjd)

Comment: I was obviously trying to over complicate things there!

Answer (score 4):

You need to delimit the regex pattern, in this case the `/` are taken as the delimiters. Use something else:

```
$pattern = '!/(.+)/!';
```